# Why does Magento (appear to) log out administrative users?

Tags: admin, login, logout

When carrying out a couple of specific (but seemingly unrelated) administrative tasks (see below for details), Magento (1.9.0.1) appears to log out the administrative user, presenting them with the login page.

I say "appears to" because pressing the browser's back button reveals that the user is still logged in (they can navigate to other pages and carry out other administrative tasks).

However, if they try to log in from the login page above, their login always fails.

This initially suggested to me that there was something wrong with the secure key. But disabling secure keys makes no difference.

Are there any circumstances under which Magento would be expected to behave as above?

The two scenarios both involve the use of from different third parties:

- With Mageworx's "Advanced Product Options" (4.12.0), the problem occurs when users attempt to navigate to Catalog -> Advanced Product Options
- With Bleulliette's "Enhanced Admin Grids (+ Editor)" (0.8.9), the problem occurs when users try to add a category or attribute column to Manage Products

It seems unlikely that they would have the same "bug", so it look like an issue with a common element - such as Magento core, or our site configuration.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

My first guess would be a problem related to your session, possibly one of your extensions or some customization code is [instantiating the session object too early](http://alanstorm.com/magento_sessions_early), and the request asking you to log in is using a different name for the PHP session id.  The quickest way to tell if this is the problem is to look at the cookie names for your Magento domain, and if you see a `PHPSESSID` that means Magento's not setting the session cookie name properly for one of the requests.

Comment: Thanks for the clear reply, Alan. Great article too.

But no sign of a "PHPSESSID" cookie from the site. (Although there's a "phpsysid", which I can't seem to find anything about in Google...)

Comment: @Robb that might be worth following up on -- you system might be configured to use phpsysid as the default session id instead of PHPSESSID.  Also, sounds like you might want to follow up with extension vendor support channels.

Answer (score 1):

I know the same issue that is related with one other 3-rd party extension named Extendedware PAGE CACHE. For some reason it doesn't detect MageWorx admin controller as admin. Here the solution:
Go to Extendedware PAGE CACHE > Miscellaneous > Runnable Disqualifiers > Admin URI Identifiers and point here 3-rd party admin controllers, i.e. 'mageworx' for MageWorx Customoptions.